# Convert cumulative day of year to milliseconds?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm working with an image where the value of each pixel corresponds to the day of the year, starting with 2019-01-01.

| Date | Pixel value |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 |
| 2019-01-02 | 2 |
| 2019-01-03 | 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 2022-04-11 | 1196 |

I want to convert the value of these pixels (cumulative day of year) into milliseconds, but I couldn't think of a way to do it.

Unfortunately I can't provide an image to reproduce the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `1196` should give the millis for `2022-04-11`, it seems like you want to exclude leap days altogether. Is this the case?

If you exclude leap days, it's quite simple:

```
function toMillis(day) {
  var dayOffset = ee.Date('2019-01-01')
    .difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'days')
    .subtract(1)
  return day.add(dayOffset)
    .multiply(1000) // Second to millis
    .multiply(3600) // Hour to second
    .multiply(24) // Day to hour
}
```

Otherwise, it's tricky. Since you need to do date manipulations on an image, you cannot rely on `ee.Date`, so you have to manually deal with the date logic, which is notoriously easy to get wrong. Anyway, below is my stab at implementing something like this. I'm sure there are problems with the implementation, it certainly it has some assumptions that causes this to fail if your date is too far in the future (2070s).

```
function toMillis(day) {
  var referenceYear = ee.Number(2019)
  // Could be different due to leap years. 
  var approximateYear = day.subtract(1).divide(365).floor().add(referenceYear)

  var leapYears = ee.Image(ee.Array( // Array image with leap years 
    ee.List.sequence(referenceYear, 2070)
      .map(function isLeapYear(year) {
        year = ee.Number(year)
        return ee.Date.fromYMD(year.add(1), 1, 1).advance(-1, 'day') // Last of year
          .getRelative('day', 'year').gt(364) // Got the extra day
          .multiply(year) // Return the actual year if a leap year or 0
      })
      .filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', 0))
  ))
  var numberOfLeapYears = leapYears
    .arrayMask(leapYears.lte(approximateYear)) // Mask out leap years after the year of the pixel
    .arrayLength(0) // Results in an image where the pixel value represents the number of leap years

  var leapYearAdjustedDay = day.add(numberOfLeapYears)
  var year = leapYearAdjustedDay.subtract(1).divide(365).floor().add(referenceYear)
  
  var isLeapYear = leapYears.arrayMask(leapYears.eq(year))
    .arrayLength(0)
  var januaryFirstDay = year.subtract(referenceYear).multiply(365).add(numberOfLeapYears).add(1).subtract(isLeapYear)
  var dayOfYear = leapYearAdjustedDay.subtract(januaryFirstDay).add(1)
  var isBeforeLeapDay = dayOfYear.lte(31 + 29)
  var timeOfYearAdjustment = isLeapYear.and(isBeforeLeapDay) // 1 if before leap day on leap year, otherwise 0
  var finalDay = leapYearAdjustedDay
    .subtract(timeOfYearAdjustment)
  
  var dayOffset = ee.Date.fromYMD(referenceYear, 1, 1)
    .difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'days')
    .subtract(1)
  return finalDay.add(dayOffset)
    .multiply(1000) // Second to millis
    .multiply(3600) // Hour to second
    .multiply(24) // Day to hour
}


testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(1)), '2019-01-01')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(2)), '2019-01-02')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(3)), '2019-01-03')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(365)), '2019-12-31')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(366)), '2020-01-01')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(423)), '2020-02-27')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(424)), '2020-02-28')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(425)), '2020-03-01')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(426)), '2020-03-02')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(730)), '2020-12-31')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(731)), '2021-01-01')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(732)), '2021-01-02')
testDate(toMillis(ee.Image(1196)), '2022-04-11')


function testDate(millisImage, expectedDate) {
  var millis = millisImage
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]), 1)
    .values()
    .getNumber(0)
  var date = ee.Date(millis).format('yyyy-MM-dd')
  var valid = millis.eq(ee.Date(expectedDate).millis())
  print(
    ee.Algorithms.If(valid,
      'Success: ' + expectedDate,
      ee.String('Failed: Expected ' + expectedDate + ' was ').cat(date)
    )
  )
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/16a23b3554e90c869c999de09e2fde90

Comment: Your solution worked great! I had even done it in a simpler way, but our results differed. Can you tell me where the error is and why?? Here is my solution: https://code.earthengine.google.com/bdc915faeb31201f60ec2ee7ed2cb2b2

Comment: I cannot tell what's wrong with it at a glance, but start by adding some tests to your function, that makes it easier for you to debug. https://code.earthengine.google.com/a4f7cde8928bf49c8b5d9a6f646e5318

Comment: Note that the tests I have is based on your question. Double check that this is the behavior you actually want. Are the leap days actually excluded from the alerts?