# how to transform a doy band into a date in specific format?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

Let's Assume I have a "doy" band in my `ee.Image` e.g. an integer from 0 to 365. I know the year as well (2023).
It's a typical case when dealing with deforestation alert system.

I would like to transform this band to into a string formatted band like yyyy-MM-dd?

I wanted to do something like this:

```py
def doyToDate(image, band, dateformat="yyyyMMdd", year=None):
    """Convert a DOY band to a date band."""
    doyBand = image.select(band)
    year = year or image.date().get("year")
    return ee.Image(ee.DatefromYMD(year, 1, 1).advance(boyBand, "day").format(dateFormat)
```

But then I realize I cannot add a date type band to an `ee.Image`. Is there a trick ?

Comment: Maybe one of these answers can help you out a bit, though none of them does exactly what you want: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428770/154371
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/426854/154371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was 1 very important missing information in the method I was trying t refactor (https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools/blob/d45ad99cedfb3d8e11cf9d972f3d334b94d9ad19/geetools/tools/image.py#L902), the date format must be parsable as a number as Image cannot have a string band. So in the refactored solution I decided to take advantage of the remap method and did this:

```py
def doyToDate(image, year, dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd", band="") -> ee.Image:
    """Convert the DOY band to a date band."""
    year, dateFormmat = ee.Number(year), ee.String(dateFormat)
    band = ee.String(band) if band else ee.String(image.bandNames().get(0))

    doyList = ee.List.sequence(1, 366)
    remapList = doyList.map(lambda d: ee.Number.parse(
        ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1).advance(d, "day").format(dateFormat)
    ))
    return image.remap(doyList, remapList, band)
```

Note that this will be added to the gee_tools v1 Python lib.
here is a javascript example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0d8e5c3bc9c1bd9235be064a3ab634cd

Answer (score 0):

Assume for a second that you could have a pixel with a string in it; what would you then do with that?  If the answer is: "I'd display it so I knew what day the pixel came from", or something like that, then the answer is to perform the transformation after you extract the integer DOY value from the band.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I agree with the reasoning but as I'm refactoring gee_tools I must keep this function alive for at least 1 more version to avoid regression issues. I just want to make it 100% server side as opposed to the existing one.